# Co-clustering algorithm in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

Are there implementations available for any co-clustering algorithms in python? The scikit-learn package has k-means and hierarchical clustering but seems to be missing this class of clustering.

Comment: The BiBench package introduced here: https://etd.ohiolink.edu/ap:10:0::NO:10:P10_ACCESSION_NUM:osu1332533492  looks promising.  It can be found here: http://bmi.osu.edu/hpc/software/bibench/

Answer (score 0):

The fastest clustering algorithm I know of does this:

Repeat O(log N) times:
C = M x X

Where X is N x dim and M is clus x N...

If your clusters are not "flat"...

Perform f(X) = ... This just projects X onto some "flat" space...